# How do I save a MovieClip as an image in Actionscript 3?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have created a customized dress up avatar using flash. Now I have to do that a registered user can make his avatar. After user creates his/her avatar how can I save the customized avatar in a database?

Answer (score 4):

**Save image from Flash, send it to PHP and return a URL string to Flash:**
[Save image from Flash, send it to PHP and return a URL string to Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070763/save-image-from-flash-send-it-to-php-and-return-a-url-string-to-flash/6084208#6084208)

**Send bitmap data from Flex to Php:**
[Send bitmap data from Flex to Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413051/send-bitmap-data-from-flex-to-php)

Comment: i have checked ur first link for creating image from moviecliip in flash but my question is how can i pass URLVariable with URLRequest???

Comment: by using the data property of the URLRequest. it's all laid out in the  example link Mattias provided.